# When to use a defaultdict vs using copy

Tags: python

What would be the difference between using a `copy` and a `defaultdict` approach for the below?

```
base_data = {...}

for item in iterable:

    # approach 1 <-- why wouldn't this work?
    data = defaultdict(lambda: base_data)

    # approach 2
    data = deepcopy(base_data)

    ...
```

It seems the first method is the wrong object type for this, but could someone clarify what the difference is between the two approaches, and why that wouldn't work?

Comment: that is not really the usecase of `defaultdict`, so use `deepcopy`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. The two are creating completely different data. The first is a dictionary of infinitely many ``base_data``s (each being the same object, by the way), the second is just the equivalent of a single ``base_data``.

Comment: I am honestly have a hard time understanding what you are asking. These do totally different things.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see -- want to put together an answer showing the difference and then I'll accept that. I'm probably confused myself on when to use which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `deepcopy` makes a brand new deep copy of the original `dict`; the new copy is entirely separated from the original, so subsequent modifications to one do not affect the other at all.
2. `defaultdict(lambda: base_data)` makes a `dict` that, whenever a bracketed lookup for a key fails, inserts that key with a value that's an alias of `base_data` (so modifying any value would modify all of them, the same way `b = a` followed by a mutating operation on `a` or `b` affects both).

   `defaultdict`'s default "constructor" should always return an immutable type (aliases okay since they can't be mutated) or a brand new freestanding mutable type (e.g. for `base_data` with immutable values, a shallow copy with `defaultdict(base_dict.copy)` works; for `base_data` with mutable values, you'd need a deep copy to keep them independent, `defaultdict(lambda: copy.deepcopy(base_data))`, or just copying the literal that defined `base_data` into the `lambda` if it's short enough).

#1 has a use case (making an entirely independent copy that can be updated without affecting other copies).

#2, as you wrote it, just doesn't; many aliases of a mutable type shared between all keys is essentially useless; you'd need copying or fresh construction to default to a mutable value to make a useful `defaultdict`.

Comment: I see, so `defaultdict` only has one object and any mutations to that affect all objects that reference it? Even if that lookup occurred before it was changed?

Comment: @David542: It's because you used a `lambda` that returned a single existing object without copying it in any way, rather than making a new one; it's the same as doing `a = b`, you make aliases, not copies. Useful cases for `defaultdict` either: 1) Return an immutable value (so it would be replaced when changed, not modified in place) or 2) Construct a new value on demand. `defaultdict(base_dict.copy)` would be fine if `base_dict`'s values were all immutable; if not, you'd use `defaultdict(lambda: copy.deepcopy(base_dict))` to ensure each value is new and disconnected from the others.

Comment: Ah, ok that's a great explanation -- thank you! Would you want to add that comment-part into your answer and I'll go ahead and accept it?

Comment: @David542: Done (with rephrasing).

Comment: thanks, in a way it's almost like I'm instantiating a crude class using the `copy(base_dict)` each time. Maybe I should just turn that into a class?